# Rails-2 Mysql to MSSQL converstion - (NULL) display in form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have successfully migrated  my Rails (2.3.18) application DB Mysql to MSSQL-2012 by using SSMA Tool.

I had 25 tables in my DB, all the data are migrated well. In my all tables few columns are accepting NULL values.

For example :

**In MYSQL =>** If I load the User Registration form, All the text fields are loaded with empty values to users to type the corresponding values in it.

In case of MSSQL

**In MSSQL =>** If I load the User Registration form, All the text fields are appeared  with value (NULL) to users to type the corresponding values in it.

I googled  and found we should set something like **:default  NULL false** attribute

It seems I have to open every table and its each column to set this attribute. It becomes difficult.

Is there any way to remove displaying **(NULL)** in all new forms. Please help thanks in advance

Comment: There should be a way to do this on the database end, but what happens if you do `Model.new(attribute: "", attribute2: "")`?

Comment: It used it but no luck  @clark

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this in Ruby, but doing it like this in Jquery may work. However you should definitely fix the databases.

```
$(document).ready(function() {               //On document ready
    $("form").find('input').each(function(){ //find all inputs in forms
        if ($(this).val() == "(NULL)") {     //if the value of an input is "(NULL)"
            $(this).val("");                 //Set it to ""
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Yeah. It should work. But as you said this above solution is a alternative.  I should find the DB level change. Thanks for the answer Mr. Clark